# R function to label a point contained within a polygon

Tags: r, polygon, point, r-sf

I've got a couple of data frames with a geom column, one of points (a bunch of addresses) and one of polygons (districts).
I want to add a column to the points data frame that states the district that it is contained in, based on the location of the points.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely looking for `sf::st_join()` - it performs a spatial join between two sf class data objects. It is often used for point-in-polygon operation, such as the one you describe.

Consider this example, built on the well known and much loved NC shapefile that ships with the sf package, and three semi random NC cities. It will give a county dimension (from the county polygons) to a point based sf data frame.

Note that the `st_join()` operation has by default behavior of a left join in SQL speak; if you desire inner join behavior you need to specify left = FALSE in the join parameters.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# the county polygons
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

# 3 semi random NC cities
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                  x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                  y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(shape)) # align coordinate systems

# here be the action!
cities_with_counties <- st_join(cities,
                                shape,
                                left = F) %>% # not left = inner join
  select(name, county = NAME) # just a few columns; rename county name from shape object

# lo and behold! cities with county names :)
cities_with_counties
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.81969 ymin: 34.22316 xmax: -77.91251 ymax: 36.07986
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#         name      county                   geometry
# 1    Raleigh        Wake POINT (-78.63361 35.76652)
# 2 Greensboro    Guilford POINT (-79.81969 36.07986)
# 3 Wilmington New Hanover POINT (-77.91251 34.22316)
```